# Sorting of array of dictionaries by using key of dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nssortdescriptor

```
    {
        "restaurant name" : "str1",
         "distance": 19.4
    }
    {
        "restaurant name" : "str2",
         "distance": 2.1
    {
        "restaurant name" : "str3",
         "distance":19.3
    }
    {
        "restaurant name" : "str4",
         "distance": 2.1
    }
```

Above is my array of dictionary values restaurant name and key. I have used following code but it is not sorting properly. It is showing sequence 19.3 ,19.4, 2.1, 2.1. I think it is comparing only first digit

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kRestaurantListDistance ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
[restaurantList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];
```

Please tell me proper code to sort out array in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try this :

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    float distance1 = [[obj1 objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue];
    float distance2 = [[obj2 objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue];

    if (distance1 < distance2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (distance1 > distance2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's sorting by the first digit, that means that your numbers are, in fact, just strings.

Two possible approaches:

1. Before you sort then, convert them to numbers (it's in a dictionary, so they'll have to be `NSNumbers` rather than simple floats)
2. Create your own compare method or block (I typically prefer to use `initWithKey:ascending:comparator:`)

Which approach you use depends on what you do with the dictionary afterwards. If you need numbers again later, 1 is probably best; otherwise 2.

Answer (score 0):

**You can maybe try this. it will work :**

```
arrWholeArrImg=[NSMutableArray sortArray:_arrWholeArrImg string:@"CategoryName"];

    +(NSMutableArray *)sortArray:(NSMutableArray *)arr  string:(NSString *)key {
   NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
   sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key
                                                       ascending:YES];
   NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
   NSArray  *sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
                    arr = [sortedArray mutableCopy];
                    return arr;
    }
```